# What kind of extra feedback would be useful for moderation/reviewing?

Tags: discussion, review

I would like to gather some feedback on availability and ease of access to information (statistics) about my moderation and reviewing. Similar info as available for flags, where you go to the profile page and click on the number after "helpful flags" and get an idea how you are doing.

Reviewing the flag information helped with determining what were wrong applications of the flags by me, and allowed me to improve on "flagging".

For other areas this kind of input is not available (AFAIK), or not at an early stage. E.g. you can only easily look at how others voted to close on reviews by the time you have a rep that you should have a relative good grasp of reviewing this anyway. It would be useful to have a page much earlier (rep wise), where you can see your own reviews that had a different outcome than what you voted (maybe that is there but I missed it), and this information could be more  anonymous than the history link available to high rep users (which shows the names of the other reviewers):

```
4 out of 5 U&L other reviewers recommended deleting this post
```

Another case, the one that triggered this question, is based on a recent comment from a Michael Mrozek about an answer that I reviewed (Low Quality queue IIRC) and where I, and two reviewers before me, voted to delete because it looked like a comment/request for clarification. Michael preferred to change to change the answer to something looking more like a real answer. Having been made aware of that, I will keep that in mind and do that myself. Without that comment addressed to me however, I would probably never have noticed. And I have no clue how often this has happened in the past, nor where I could get info about this.

If we answer here (possible as wiki answers), we could use the voting mechanism on the answers to determine opinions on usefulness and then make a combined feature request at some point based on that. Or, if the poster missed some already available mechanism to get information, the answer could be marked with a clear:

### this information is already available

and help future visitors looking for this information in one place, together with information about feedback/statistics what they cannot hope to find (yet).

---

This is not a feature request or support request on existing features on its own. As I indicated, it is intended as a discussion item, possible resulting in a feature request distilled from the information here.
It is also not intended to eventually make voting etc. more uniform, being able to review once actions compared to others doesn't mean one **has to** change, but could help those who are interested, to focus on a potential different way of (re-)acting.

Comment: +1, good Q. I too remember being dissatisfied w/ the exposure to these things.

Comment: Once you've voted on a review item, you can see how others voted on that item, and you can go back to that item in your activity list. For statistical data, you can find historical information in the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/), e.g. [my contested suggested edit reviews](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79860/my-contested-suggested-edit-reviews), [How often do people edit in LQP review?](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/199503/how-often-do-people-edit-in-lqp-review)

Answer (score 2):

### Close Votes review queue

#### Current state:

For some historical information you can look at the history tab in the Close Votes (CV) review queue. This allows you to correlate your action (3rd column) with an action at the end of the question title, if any (`[closed]`, `[duplicate]`).

Clicking the action link (`Close`, `Leave Open`) brings up a page where one can see how others voted (without any detail on Close reason) on this review item (so you can only see this after you cast your vote, because there is no entry in the history yet if you didn't).

At 10K rep the primary difference is that the overview includes the actions of other reviewers (names in the first column), even for items you have not voted upon yet. This makes it only marginally more easy to compare actions as the entries cannot be sorted by review item and votes by different reviewers on a particular item are seldom contiguous.

#### Possible improvements:

- An easier way of viewing which reviews had a different result then ones own action (e.g. as a filter on the history list, like you can include skipped items). Differentiate between being single differing reviewer, or more heavily disputed items (i.e. multiple reviewers that voted different than the final decision).
- Statistical information about your own review action being aligned or not with the other reviewers.
- Detail on aligned reviews, i.e. reason for closure. Thereby being able to answer such questions as: "Do others vote to close for being to broad as often as I do")
- Some way to mark review items as something to come back to, to see how others voted (once a consensus is reached). Currently the only thing one can do is make a bookmark in your browser before concluding the review, or search for the in your review activity history (activity → review in your profile).